# Windows 10 Factory Reset - request to clear TPM - what data is cleared

Tags: windows-10, acer-aspire, tpm

I'm trying to preform a factory reset on my Acer Aspire laptop with a full clean disk.

I've been met with a black and blue screen with the message

> A configuration change was requested to clear this computer's TPM (Trusted Platform Module)
>
> WARNING: Clearing erases information stored on the TPM. You will lose all created keys and access to data encrypted by these keys.
>
> Press YES to clear the TPM
>
> Pres NO to reject this change request and continue

I'm wondering what kind of data this will delete? I want to start fresh and have Windows 10 reinstall itself again. But will it delete important keys like the Product Key and data for the OS reinstallation? Or will it just delete old encrypted file like videos, music, pictures, documents, etc that I don't care about - therefore I should choose YES.

I'm not reinstalling Windows 10 from a USB or DVD btw.

Comment: Unless you are using Bitlocker to encrypt your drive, TPM being cleared, isn't important.  Your license key is stored in the ACPI table.  It will automatically be detected when you install Windows 10.  You also have a digital entitlement, which means, your installation will automatically be activated.  If your using Bitlocker, you will want to turn it off before you perform the factory reset, then reenable it after Windows 10 is up and running

Comment: I've already started the Factory Reset, so I'm stuck now. I also never encrypted my hard drive with Bitlocker before unless it was setup this way when I bought the laptop from the retail store! So its ok to select YES